# If Condition always fails in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, if-statement

The following is the code on a jsp page..This is a user login page..

```
<form onsubmit="return userValidation()" action="tempTestingPage.jsp" method="post">
                <table>
                    <b><h3 style="text-align: center">Welcome back!</h3></b>
                    <h5 style="text-align: center">Sign in to continue to your account</h5>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>User Name</label></td>
                        <td><input autofocus type="text" id="userloginid" name="LoginID" required="Enter your user name here"</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><br><label>Password</label></td>
                        <td><br><input type="text" id="userloginpassword" name="LoginPassword" required="Enter your Password here"</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <br><input type="submit" style="width: 33%; border-radius: 10px; border-color: #ea0f1f;" value="Sign in">
                </div>

                <br><div id="registerlogin" style="text-align: center;">
                    Not Registered Yet? <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #8a2de3;" href="RegistrationForm.jsp" >Register Here</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
```

I have written my code in such a way that upon the submission of the above form if javascript function returns true it navigates to another jsp page i.e. tempTestingPage.jsp . Otherwise, the following error is shown by making its visibilty visible in the javascript function. All the javascript code below is also written on the above jsp page.

```
<div id="invalidusernameorpassword" style="visibility: hidden">
        <fieldset style="position: absolute; left: 37.4%; top: 7%; display: block; background-color: #fae4a8 ;width: 26%; height: 9.3%; border: 4px; border-color: #cd8686; border-style: solid;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><h4 style="font-family: sans-serif; text-align: left; margin-top: 0%; margin-bottom: 0%; color: #f40909; font-weight: bold;">There was a problem with your request.</h4></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p style="font-family: sans-serif; text-align: left; font-size: 74%; margin-top: 0%; color: #f40909;">There was an error with your Username or Password combination. Please try again.</p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Here is my javascript function userValidation() which is invoked upon form submission:
In this code, I am sending an ajax request to servlet UserPermissionServlet to find out whether the username and password entered is a correct combination. If correct combination, "found" is returned as a response. Otherwise "not found" is returned. No matter what the response is..the if condition always fails and statements in else part gets executed. Alerts are placed in the code just for my reference.

```
function userValidation() {
        var result = ajaxForPermissionInside("UserPermissionServlet?data1=" + document.getElementById("userloginid").value + "&data2=" + document.getElementById("userloginpassword").value);
        alert(result);
        if(result === "found"){
            alert("In If Condition");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            alert("In else Condition");
            document.getElementById("invalidusernameorpassword").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("userloginid").focus();
            document.getElementById("userloginid").value = "";
            document.getElementById("userloginpassword").value = "";
            return false;
        }
}

function ajaxForPermissionInside(url) {
    var myrequest1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myrequest1.open("POST", url, false);
    myrequest1.send(null);
    return(myrequest1.responseText);
}
```

The servlet code is here:

```
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        if(userAccount== 1)
            out.println("found");
        else out.println("not found");
    }
```

Please help me figure out what is wrong with my javascript code.

Comment: is `result` actually printed as `"found"` in your alert? if yes, try to use only two `==` signs. 
I don't know much about jsp, but maybe you can/should change `out.println("found");` to something like `return "found";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out.println()` adds a newline after the message. You're comparing it with a string that doesn't have a newline.

Use `out.print()` instead.

Comment: Thanks a million Mr. Barmar... I have been trying this for the whole day but couldnt figure it out...